# how to get an html object[data value ] from an array of same html element object

Tags: jquery

How do i get the data object from a html Object that has more than one like element in an array.

```
<div id='show_box'>
    <h6 id="#0" data-choosed="1000">1000</h6>
    <h6 id="#1" data-choosed="1000">2000</h6>
    <h6 id="#2" data-choosed="1000">3000</h6>
</div>
```

In the javascript    `var h6_len=$("#show_box > h6").length;`

```
         switch (h6_len) {
            case 0:
                 choosed=$('#show_box > #' + h6_len).data('choosed');

                $('#total_box').text(choosed);// this return the drop-down clicked
              //this part of the code is working fine.. when the case == 0
              break;
        case 1:
              var h6_1=$('#show_box > h6')[0];
                  var h6_2=$('#show_box > h6')[1];

                  /* this is where i am having issues... getting the data value from one of the array the H6 element...

                  console.log( typeof h6_1);
                  break;
            case 2:
                  console.log(h6_len);
                  break;
                  default:
                  $('#total_box').empty();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id='show_box'>
    <h6 id="#0" data-choosed="1000">1000</h6>
    <h6 id="#1" data-choosed="2000">2000</h6>
    <h6 id="#2" data-choosed="3000">3000</h6>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('h6').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).data('choosed'));
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7g5H/1/)**. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: var h6_1=$('#show_box > h6')[0];
                  var h6_2=$('#show_box > h6')[1];

                  /* this is where i am having issues... getting the data value from one of the array the H6 element...

Comment: when the case is one there are 2 html objects h6_1=$('#show_box > h6')[0];var h6_2=$('#show_box > h6')[1]; that is why i made it in an array but i want to get the data value "$('#show_box > h6')[0].data('choosed')" but it returns undefined. please what can i do to get the data from the two object.

Comment: @user3223851 It would be great if you can create a fiddle to show when is switch case fired and show the error in the console..